# django aggregation: sum then average

Tags: python, django, orm

Using django's ORM `annotate()` and/or `aggregate()`: I want to sum up based on one category field and then average over the category values per date. I tried to do it using two `annotate()` statements but got a `FieldError`.

I'm doing this:

```
queryset1 = self.data.values('date', 'category').annotate(sum_for_field=Sum('category'))
```

Which outputs a `ValuesQuerySet` object with things like (so a sum for each value of category):

```
[{'category': 'apples', 'date': '2015-10-12', sum_for_field=2000},
 {'category': 'carrots', 'date': '2015-10-12', sum_for_field=5000},
 {'category': 'apples', 'date': '2015-10-13', sum_for_field=3000},
 {'category': 'carrots', 'date': '2015-10-13', sum_for_field=6000}, ...
]
```

I then want to average the `sum_for_field` field for each date to output something like:

```
[ {'date': '2015-10-12', avg_final: 3500},
{'date': '2015-10-13', avg_final: 4500}, ...
]
```

I tried doing this:

```
queryset2 = queryset1.values('date', 'sum_for_field')
result = queryset2.annotate(avg_final=Avg('sum_for_field'))
```

But I got this `FieldError`:

```
FieldError: FieldError: Cannot compute Avg('sum_for_field'): 'sum_for_field' is an aggregate
```

Comment: You need to change `.annotate()` to `.aggregate()`. See the docs for more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: @jape why don't you add this in an answer with a reference to the documentation which [provides an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations).

Comment: That example is not what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compute average of an aggregate in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021616/how-to-compute-average-of-an-aggregate-in-django)

Comment: @EminMastizada It is not a duplicate because the result of that related is one average value of Sum by groups. It can be expressed by one SQL. This presumed duplicated question requires many result averages, therefore nested queries with group by. Neither the new [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) class in Django 1.11 is not however enough for it.

Comment: @user1387717 Have you found a solution to this in the end? I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 11):

Aggregate annotation by group from many aggregate annotations by group is generally a complicated question, but **`Avg` from `Sum`** is a special **much easier** case.

Expression `Avg('sum_for_field')`  can be evaluated as `Sum('sum_for_field') / Count('category',  distinct=True)` that can be evaluated by [Aggregate() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions). The `Sum('sum_for_field')` equals `Sum('amount')`.

**Solution**: (Expected names: The model is `Data` that has fields `date`, `category`, `amount`.)

```
qs = Data.objects.values('date').annotate(
    avg_final=Sum('amount') / Count('category', distinct=True)
)
```

(I'm convinced that very similar questions would be without any solution by current Django 1.11, even with Subquery class, without using a strange extra() method and without raw SQL)

Answer (score -1):

I haven't done a deep dive, but I suspect that when you use `values()` without an annotation, `sum_for_field` values are being merged with ones that share the same `date`. I think you need to evaluate the annotation right after you use a [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#values) clause. Maybe something like below will resolve your issue:

`result = queryset1.values('date').annotate(avg_final=Avg('sum_for_field'))`