# How to compute average of an aggregate in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

If I have an aggregate, can I get the average of the values in the query, without computing it in python memory?

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum, FloatField, Avg
Model.objects.filter(...)\
    .values('id')\
    .annotate(subtotal=Sum(...math here...), output_field=FloatField())\
    .annotate(total=Avg(F('subtotal'))) #this line throws a FieldError
```

Is there any way to get the `Avg` of the `subtotal` values in the query? It gives me an error that I'm not allowed to compute `Avg` on an aggregate ("`subtotal`"), but I can't replace the `.values('id')` grouping because the `.annotate(...math here...)` operations inside aren't [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) accross `Model` objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum, FloatField, Avg
Model.objects.filter(...)\
    .values('id')\
    .annotate(subtotal=Sum(...math here..., output_field=FloatField()))\
    .aggregate(total=Avg(F('subtotal')))
```

[Aggregating annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations). Note: `output_field` is parameter of `Sum`, not `annotate()`.

Comment: I've got same problem but I need to average over multiple (already) aggregated fields.  Something like `.aggregate(total=Avg(F('subtotal_1'), F('subtotal_2'), F('subtotal_3')))` but it complains saying `subtotal_1` is an aggregate... how to solve this? [Here's a similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911474/django-aggregation-sum-then-average)

Comment: Make sure that the annotated field has a different name from the aggregate field name. Else a confusing error arises, that is not easily connected to field naming.